# Find optimal paramters for target value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, scalar, n-dimensional

I have some code that takes parameters `x1, x2... xn` and outputs the value `y`. I want to find the parameters that maximize `y`. I picked randomly the parameters 1000 times, calculated the target value and wrote the data to pandas dataframe. So my dataframe has 1000 rows and `n+1` columns, `n` for parameters and 1 for target value. What next? In calculus I would derive the function that I want to maximize and look for the derivative zeros. The problem is that I don't have the analytical expression of the function, just the code which calculates it. Clearly it is not simply to return the row of parameters with maximal `y` because it is possible that a different combination of parameters will produce higher values for `y`.

Comment: This sound very much like [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent).